# How to create an object after deserialization in c# in xml

Tags: c#, wpf, deserialization

I am trying to create an object after deserialization however I do not want to serialize that object.
Here is an example:

```cs
public class Visit : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id;
    private int serialNumber;
    private DateTime dateOfVisit;
    private VisitTime visitTime;
    private VisitType visitType;
    private int price;
    private VisitStatus visitStatus;
    private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;
    private String cause;
    private String recommendation;
    private Prescription prescription;
    private Patient patient;
    [NonSerialized]
    private Doctor doctor;
    private Room room;

    // more code below...
}
```

I do not want to serialize the doctor, I have the doctors in completely different xml file. I am serializing doctorID property fine. After deserialization of the properties that I have serialized I want to create a new instance of a Doctor class and assign it to doctor field in Visit class. How can I do that correctly?

Here is the xml that I am serializing:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfVisit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Visit>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <SerialNumber>1</SerialNumber>
    <VisitTime>
        <StartTime>2021-05-02T09:00:00</StartTime>
        <EndTime>2021-05-02T10:00:00</EndTime>
    </VisitTime>
    <DateOfVisitString>1. Jan 00:00 AM</DateOfVisitString>
    <DateOfVisit>0001-01-01T00:00:00</DateOfVisit>
    <VisitType>examination</VisitType>
    <VisitTypeString>Pregled</VisitTypeString>
    <Price>10</Price>
    <PriceString>10$</PriceString>
    <VisitStatus>forthcoming</VisitStatus>
    <VisitStatusString>Predstojeći</VisitStatusString>
    <DoctorName>Janko Radovic</DoctorName>
    <DoctorId>12123131</DoctorId>
    <PaymentMethod>digitalWallet</PaymentMethod>
    </Visit>
</ArrayOfVisit>
```

I tried using onDeserializing() and onDeserialized() methods but I get a null pointer exception when data is binded to View with DoctorName property. It just says doctor is null.

```cs
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
public Doctor Doctor
{
    get
    {
        return doctor;
    }
    set
    {
        doctor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Doctor");
        OnPropertyChanged("DoctorName");
        OnPropertyChanged("DoctorId");
    }
}

public String DoctorName
{
    get
    {
        return doctor.Name + " " + doctor.Surname;
    }
    set
    {

    }
}

public String DoctorId
{
    get
    {
        return doctor.Id;
    }
    set
    {

    }
}

[OnDeserialized()]
internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
{
    DoctorService doctorService = new DoctorService();
    doctor = doctorService.getDoctorById(DoctorId);
}
```

Here is how I serialize and deserialize:

```cs
public void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
{
    if (serializableObject == null) { return; }
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());
    try
    {
        var temp = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        temp = Path.Combine(temp.Substring(0, temp.Length - 10), "Storage\\");
        fileName = Path.Combine(temp, fileName);
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fileName);
        serializer.Serialize(w, serializableObject);
        w.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Log exception here
    }
}

public T DeSerializeObject<T>(string fileName)
{
    var temp = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    temp = Path.Combine(temp.Substring(0, temp.Length - 10), "Storage\\");
    fileName = Path.Combine(temp, fileName);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) { return default(T); }
    T objectOut = default(T);

    try
    {
        Type outType = typeof(T);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(outType);

        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fileName);
        objectOut = (T)serializer.Deserialize(r);
        r.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Log exception here
    }

    return objectOut;
}
```

Any suggestion how I can do this? Just serialize the id and then by using that id to create a Doctor object in Visit class? Thank you!

Comment: Can't you implement the setter of the `DoctorId` property to set the `Doctor` property to a new object with that id?

Comment: That actually did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to mm8 who suggested a thing that worked out this is how it should be done.
XMLSerializer works with get and set properties of a model class. So when serializing a particular class object the way serialization works is that it uses get method of that property to serialize. To deserialize it uses set method to again set the fields of that class object that was serialized.

If you do not want to serialize a particular field of a class you should just set `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]` above your property. I only wanted to serialize an id of an Doctor class and I did it by making a property:

```
public String DoctorId
    {
        get
        {
            return doctor.Id;
        }
        set
        {
            DoctorService doctorService = new DoctorService();
            doctor = doctorService.getDoctorById(value);
        }

}
```

When deserializing a set method is called `value` is equal to serialized doctor's id. Then a service is used which finds the doctor from some other repository and it sets the doctor field in the Visit class.